# limitation for client nodes in free SQLServer Express

Tags: sql

is there any limitation for client nodes in free SQLServer Express. How many nodes it supports in multiuser environment ?

Answer (score 2):

"SQL Server Express (SSE) doesn't have any concurrent user or connection limit that is specific to the SKU."

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/d5526173-572e-4c05-bedb-f48d010c9b13) MSDN forums thread.

If you are talking about the number of instances on a machine, that is 16, as documented in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154%28SQL.90%29.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: Doesn't the 5 concurrent user limit apply to MSDE? I believe it's gone for SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any limit to the number of concurrent users:
"There is no hard-coded limit to the number of users that can attach to SQL Server Express but their CPU and memory limits impose practical limits on the number of users that can achieve acceptable response times from a SQL Server Express database" from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154%28SQL.90%29.aspx) (that has already been mentioned previously).

If you're pushing it that hard then you really ought to have one of the non-free versions anyhow.